# React - How to sync front-end with back-end requests without using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

When I'm trying to do a validation in react JS I normally have to create a set time out function to sync the fetch api calls with front end as the fetch api calls take a bit of time. Is there are any other way to do this? Something that's under best practices and not recurring codes?

I have been using set time out with 4000-5000, it works, but i feel as if that's not the best way to do so.

edit-
Below is the code snippet of what i did before using timeout, but for some reason when the function runs, 'existingTrains' disappears from state.

```
async getExistingReservations(date, trackNo, direction, noTickets) {

        let self = this;
        var trains;
        var ticketRange = 100 - noTickets;

        var data = {
            "date": date,
            "trackNo": trackNo,
            "direction": direction
        }

        console.log(data);

        //get Existing Reservation Details
        await fetch('http://localhost:5000/resRecords/getSeats', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json)
                trains = json.find(function (tickets) {
                    return tickets.noTickets < ticketRange

                })
                self.setState({
                        existingTrains: trains
                    }
                )
            });

    }
```

Comment: That is absolutely not the best way to do that; it's probably the worst. Look into Promises.

Comment: Hello Shakeel. You usually don't need to use any `setTimeout` in React. If you can share with us an example of your code, we could show you how to do it  without `setTimeout`.

Comment: did you miss `async` keyword before the function `getExistingReservations` on your post ?

Comment: oh. yes.. sorry. Thanks for pointing it out. updated. @dqlgnoleht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to resolve this is by using `async -> await`.

```
const getNetworkRequest = async (): string => {
  const r = await makeNetworkRequest();
  console.log(r);

  if(r.data){ return 'got it!' } 
  return 'no data :(';
}
```